# How to force my tablet to remember which video files it was playing and make it easy to resume playing these files next time device is powered up?

Tags: video, standby, bookmarks

I am using Samsung Note 10.1 to watch lots of instructional videos; each course is composed of 10-40 video files, stored in folders, subfolders etc

I have tried bunch of video players; most of them can play videos ok, but once the device is rebooted I have to do the whole process again (start video player, point it to certain folder, scroll through the files I have seen already etc)

Here is my question - is it possible to force video player to start playing from the last position the player has been stopped at? (and later been able to jump to the next file from that folder etc)

*As an alternative fix* - would it be possible to switch my tablet into "deep-sleep" (**hibernation**?) mode so it could stay in such mode for a *long long time without draining the battery* and, once waken up, restore last work session)?

Comment: Can you not just lock it and charge it occasionally. Is battery life that slim for you?

Comment: @VarnerBeast14 no, this wouldn't work ...I really need either hibernation mode or video player which could save and restore it's state